# Excel VBA - Get row of latest change in a parameter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large data set which looks like this:

```
  Employee ID |Job| Function| Level|Date of change
     1        | x |   a     |  A1  | 01/05/2014   
     1        | y |   a     |  A1  | 02/04/2015  
     1        | y |   a     |  A2  | 25/08/2015   
     1        | z |   a     |  A3  | 27/12/2015   
     1        | z |   c     |  A3  | 01/03/2016  
     2        | t |   b     |  B1  | 12/05/2013  
     2        | v |   b     |  B1  | 13/04/2014   
     2        | w |   b     |  B3  | 12/01/2016
```

Each row contains a change in either job, function or level.

I need to create a table which puts together the latest change in level for each employee (so for employee 1, it would be row 4). So far I have used a combination of conditional formatting and pivots but I was wondering if there is a way to do this quicker in VBA.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like it would be better done in a data base (if the information has come from there).  On the subject of sticking to pivots, have you tried the macro recorder to create a pivot table with max function?

Comment: Thanks, I will try the pivot+max function. I only have the data in Excel as I don't have access to the database it comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without VBA

This assumes that there are genuine dates in column **E** with format `dd/mm/yyyy`, In **G1** enter the *Array Formula*:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=1,E:E,""))
```

This gives the latest date for employee **1**

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Then in **G2** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A9=1)*(E1:E9=G1)*(ROW(1:9)))
```

This gives the **row number** of the record you are interested in.

[image]

From there you can use *INDEX()* to get any information from that row.

*NOTE:*

The formulas in **G1** and **G2** can be combined into a single cell if desired.

**EDIT#1:**

The same set of formulas should work with *text values* for the employee id as well as numbers:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!This works great for text as well. However, I need to identify the latest change in level only, so for employee E123456 that would be row 5 since the level (A3) stayed the same in the next row. Any idea how to change the formula to get that? I am thinking something along the lines of OFFSET but I cannot figure it out entirely.

Comment: @Ioana  I will think about it also.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I sorted this out using a little bit of VBA and then VLOOKUP. I am posting the solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best solution, but since this is a one-off exercise and it did the trick I used this:

1. VBA to find all the rows where there was a change in level, and write a "yes" in column "F" where applicable:

   ```
   Sub JLChange()
   Dim Data As Worksheet
   Dim i As Long
   Dim lastrow As Long

   Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
   lastrow = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 1 To lastrow
       If Cells(i + 1, 4).Value <> Cells(i, 4).Value And_
              Cells(i + 1,1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
          Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = "Yes"
       Else
          Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = "No"
       End If
   Next i

   End Sub
   ```
2. For all the records in column "F", I used the formulas suggested by Gary's student to get the very last change.

Alternatively, you can copy-paste this database of changes in a new sheet, sort by ID and by date of change from newest to oldest, then use vlookup to get the first entry for each ID.